# How can I find identical rows in different arrays regardless of element order using Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was working on a project and stumbled upon this problem.
I have two arrays A and B of shape (8,3) and (2,2). How can I find all the rows of A that contain elements of each row of B regardless of the order of the elements in B?

```
A = np.random.randint(0,5,(8,3))
B = np.random.randint(0,5,(2,2))
```

Thanks!

Comment: each row -> any row or all rows?

Comment: Hi, i am interested in all rows!

Comment: You mean the set of rows in A that contain all elements in B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one way to do it:

```
Import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0,5,(8,3))
B = np.random.randint(0,5,(2,2))

C = (A[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis] == B)
rows = np.where(C.any((3,1)).all(1))[0]
print(rows)
```

**Output:**

```
[0 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(0, 5, (8, 3))
B = np.random.randint(0, 5, (2, 2))

for BRow in B:
    for ARow in A:
        if all(item in ARow for item in BRow):
            print(f'{BRow} in {ARow}')
```

This doesn't check for duplicates though, eg it accepts `[3, 3] in [1, 2, 3]`